# Issue in signup and redirecting to home page using firebase and js

Tags: javascript, firebase

when i am siging up my code is redirecting me to homepage but the data is not getting stored in realtime database.

```
function SignUp(){
    var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;

    if(password == password2) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res) => { 
            database.ref('User/'+auth.currentUser.uid).set({
                name: name,
                phone:phone,
                password: password2,
            });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                alert(error.message);
            });
    }
    else{
        alert("password didnt match");
        document.querySelector('.form_container').reset();
    }
    window.location.href = "index.html";    
}
```

This is redirecting me to my home page.But the data is not getting stored into the real-time database.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
var database = firebase.database();

function SignUp(){
    var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;

    if(password == password2) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((res) => {
            database.ref('User/'+auth.currentUser.uid).set({
                email:email,
                name: name,
                phone:phone,
                password: password2,
            });
            document.getElementById('success').style.display='block';
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                alert(error.message);
            });
    }
    else{
        alert("password didnt match");
        document.querySelector('.form_container').reset();
    }
}

function success(){
    window.location.href = "../index.html";
}
```

In the signup form

```
<div class="success_container" id="success">
    <div class="animate success">
      <p>successfully signed up</p>
      <button type="button" onclick="success()">back to site</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Add this code and that lets your job done.
Thanks